# How to make a form that can add an unlimited amount of elements

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to make my schools web-site for students. In this site i want to allow them create project page. In project page I want to allow them to upload unlimited number of files that can be dowloaded by other users. [Image from template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhZLI.png)

How I can do that

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class News(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable = False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    face_image = models.ImageField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    id = models.UUIDField( 
         primary_key = True, 
         default = uuid.uuid4, 
         editable = False)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created"]
class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profileimages/', default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=130)
    Date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True, region="UZ")
    job = models.CharField(null=True, blank= True, max_length=50)
    id = models.UUIDField( 
         primary_key = True, 
         default = uuid.uuid4, 
         editable = False)
    about = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
# Create your models here.
class Skills(models.Model):
    skills = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Project(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    category = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    cost = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, default="0.0$", max_length=10)
    profit = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, default="Non-profit", max_length = 11)
    time = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=10)
    Website = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    mission = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vision = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id = models.UUIDField( 
         primary_key = True, 
         default = uuid.uuid4, 
         editable = False)
class projectfiles(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to ='projectfiles/')
    field_name = 'id'
    obj = Project.objects.first()
    field_value = getattr(obj, field_name)
```

As you can see I tried to create another model with file field and with project ID and if IDs match template should show the file but that didn't work(gave error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: base_project, but i think even without error it wouldn't work because of ). I used same tactics in Skills model to show users skills in profile page, but with user nickname which is unique. [Image of profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx4cv.png)

```
<h4 class="card-title mb-4">My Skill</h4>
                    <div class="d-flex gap-2 flex-wrap">
                        {% for i in skill %}
                        {% if i.user == user.user%}
                        <span class="badge badge-soft-secondary p-2">{{i.skills}}</span>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
```

I can't use nickname to projects because person can have multiple projects. I need something to identify project and use this to do same method as in Skills or another method that can solve my problem